# Creating new angular project resulted to EINTEGRITY error

Tags: angular

I'm creating a new angular project using angular/cli command "ng new package" but got EINTEGRITY error.

> 14757 verbose unlock done using  C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-
>       cache_locks\staging-efa3a6df79e99f25.lock for C:\Users\XXX\Documents\my-angular-apps\second-angular-app\node_modules.staging
>       14758 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
>       14759 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\my-angular-apps\second-angular-app\node_modules.staging\fsevents-68eb5ab2\node_modules\tweetnacl' -> 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\my-angular-apps\second-angular-app\node_modules.staging\tweetnacl-77dc5269'
>       14760 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL 
>   DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>       14760 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>       14761 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: selenium-webdriver@3.0.1 (node_modules\selenium-webdriver):
>       14762 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\my-angular-apps\second-angular-app\node_modules.staging\selenium-webdriver-cdcd385c\lib\test\data\js\tinymce.min.js'
>       14763 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>       14763 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>       14764 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL 
>   DEPENDENCY: selenium-webdriver@2.53.3 (node_modules\webdriver-js-extender\node_modules\selenium-webdriver):
>       14765 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\my-angular-apps\second-angular-app\node_modules.staging\selenium-webdriver-121a8fdb\lib\firefox\webdriver.xpi'
>       14766 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>       14766 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>       14767 verbose type OperationalError
>       14768 verbose stack Error: sha1-ckGdSovn1s51FI/YsyTlk6cRwu0= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-ckGdSovn1s51FI/YsyTlk6cRwu0= but got sha1-7xAMl4qlJbbAKHUQsYE2/Va+VHI=. (30137 bytes)
>       14768 verbose stack     at Transform.on (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ssri\index.js:275:19)
>       14768 verbose stack     at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
>       14768 verbose stack     at Transform.emit (events.js:207:7)
>       14768 verbose stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
>        14768 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>        14768 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>         Jj14769 verbose cwd C:\Users\XXX\Documents\my-angular-apps\second-angular-app
>     14770 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>      14771 verbose argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "--quiet" "install"
>       14772 verbose node v8.4.0
>       14773 verbose npm  v5.3.0
>      14774 error code EINTEGRITY
>      14775 error sha1-ckGdSovn1s51FI/YsyTlk6cRwu0= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-ckGdSovn1s51FI/YsyTlk6cRwu0= but got sha1-7xAMl4qlJbbAKHUQsYE2/Va+VHI=. (30137 bytes)
>       14776 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Shown below are the details i've gathered so far:

By running "ng --version" this is what I got

> @angular/cli: 1.3.2 
>   node: 8.4.0
>   os:  win32  ia32
>   npm: 5.3.0

This is the first time I ran "ng new packageName" command. 
And before I completely (and successfully?) installed Angular CLI using`npm install -g @angular/cli`

I got a couple of ENOTFOUND and EINTEGRITY Errors so what I simply did is rerun `npm install -g @angular/cli` until there is no error in the console. I'm not sure though if this is the reason why I'm getting this EINTEGRITY errors now.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, solved it by clearing npm cache, try:

npm cache clean --force

or this might also help:

npm cache verify